# Unable to create a site using Site template in a migrated site collection

Tags: migration, site-template

I have a SharePoint 2016 site template which is used to create sites in other site collections without any issues.

I have recently migrated SharePoint 2010 content database (Web Application) to SharePoint 2016. The site collection which is part of the migrated web application is giving [A duplicate field name "Priority" was found.] error when I am trying to use the SharePoint 2016 site template that I am usually using to create sub site.

As I mentioned, I am able to use my site template in other site collection and the problem exists only in the migrated site collection.

I spent lot of time searching about this error and most of the articles online are talking about making changes to site template but in my case, site template is good because same template is working in other site collection in the same SharePoint farm and issue exists only in migrated site collection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all the "Priority" fields in all of the Tasks lists from the source site template and tried it again. It worked. Interestingly, it retained all the "Priority" fields as well. The issue seems to be with Priority field of Task content type.